# Swift: Cannot convert type 'NSData!' to type 'NSURLRequest!'

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

I'm again confronted with a strange error in Swift.

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSData!' to type 'NSURLRequest!'
```

My code is:

```
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)

var response : NSURLResponse?
var error : NSError?

NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: error)
//The error is reported at the above line
```

What does that mean? I nowhere try to convert NSData to NSURLRequest.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `request` defined twice? For example once as a property, second time as a local variable?

Comment: @Sulthan No, I'm sure I haven't.

Comment: BTW, in Swift, you can replace `cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` with `cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`. See the Enumerations section of the Swift book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why such a message is displayed but you are missing the `&` for `inout` parameters.

```
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
```

Comment: Yeah, swift errors are pretty much garbage still :)

Comment: Thank you! Swift errors are sometimes very strange.